Problem with Salesforce audio_upload API
I am integrating with Genesys to use Einstein Conversation Insights.  In Salesforce I am calling a Genesys API to get a signed URL to the recording.  Then I call the salesforce API /voicecalls/{id}/audio_upload to load the recording into Salesforce.  I am passing the URL and Named Credential.  The response is status 500.  Unknown Server Error.  Any tips on how to successfully upload a voice recording in Salesforce?

Sounds like a problem with the Named Credential.  What if you try to make some other API call with it?  Please [edit] your post to include the Named Credential details.
